# Is '$' a function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax, dollar-sign

I am quite confused about ($) in haskell.

when I type

```
:t ($)
```

in ghci. I will get

```
:($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
```

but, when I type

```
:t ($ 3)
```

I will get

```
($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

so, why ($) accept the second argument without any error？

Comment: The `($)` function is indeed an ordinary Haskell function, but it’s also an infix operator, as are all functions whose names are entirely symbolic. Infix operators have special partial application syntax called *operator sections*, and you can read more about them here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator

Comment: @Alexis King, [not so ordinary](http://www.mail-archive.com/glasgow-haskell-users@haskell.org/msg18923.html).

Comment: @user3237465 I’m actually quite aware of that, yes, but bringing that up to a learner is only going to cause entirely unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well `($)` is an operator, which is an infix function. It's definition is pretty straightforward (in fact the only thing that makes it interesting is its *fixity*, and I'm sure google has tons of resources on that):

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

Like all operators, you can take [*sections*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) of it by applying only the first or only the second argument. This might be more obvious with the addition `(+)` operator:

```
(+ 2) -- equivalent to \x -> x + 2
(2 +) -- equivalent to \x -> 2 + x
```

The same holds for `($ 3)` - it is equivalent to `\f -> f $ 3`. The type of this function should be pretty clear then: its argument `f` has to be itself a function that takes a number and returns something else (`f :: Num a => a -> b`), and the whole function returns the same type as whatever `f` returns. That gives

```
(\f -> f $ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b
```

And consequently `($ 3) :: Num a => (a -> b) -> b`.

Comment: If (3 $) then what would be the case ? I think it would not produce any result.  Use with map (3$) [\x->x+10] , right ?

Comment: `(3 $)` won't typecheck. `$` expects its first argument to be a function.